# Powershell check status Openssh

Tags: windows, openssh

here is a piece of script, I would like to check if OpenSSH is installed on the computer, if so, I would like it not to continue executing the code. Unfortunately, I cannot access the properties of the object

```
if (Get-WindowsCapability -Online  | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH.Server*' -like "Installed")
{
  Write-Output " it's OK"
  exit 0
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0).State -eq 'Installed') { 
    Write-Host "Server is Installed..!"

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sshServer = Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'OpenSSH.Server*' -and $_.State -like "Installed" }

if ($sshServer)
{
    Write-Output "OpenSSH Server is already installed."
    exit 0
}
```